# What are Gödel's property theories

Tags: set-theory

The opening sentence of Roger Myhill's article *Paradoxes*,  in Synthese 60 (1984),
129-143, is: “Gödel said to me more than once "There never were any
set-theoretic paradoxes, but the property-theoretic paradoxes are still
unresolved"; and he may well have said the same thing in print.”

What, precisely, were Gödel's property theories. I have for a long time thought that they simply were set theories without the axiom of extensionality. But perhaps there is something more to them, e.g. something stemming from Gödel's ontological argument?

Comment: See [here](https://cs.nyu.edu/pipermail/fom/2011-September/015720.html)

Comment: Reference: Frege and Russell and the logicist project based on the idea that the "concept" is a logical concept.

Comment: See B.Russell letter to Frege (1902) [reprinted into van Heijenoort's *Sourcebook*, page 125]: "Let *w* the predicate: to be a predicate that cannot be predicated of itself." And Frege's reply (1902) [page 128]: "it seems to me that the expression 'a predicate is predicated of itself' is not exact. I would prefer to say 'a notion is predicated of its own extension'."

Comment: I know the history. Recently, the term has been used differently. See e.g. here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/npc2xd19b5uaj7f/Property%20THEORY.pdf?dl=0